# .Net Core Web Api / HttpGet / About Get ICollection

Tags: c#, .net-core, get, asp.net-core-webapi, icollection

Firstly, sorry for my English, it is not perfect. I hope i can explain my problem.

WebApi has Movie Class like this

```
    public class Movie
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int DirectorID { get; set; }
        public Director Director { get; set; }
        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    }
```

When I used HttpGet Movies
[it happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bZX7.png)

It cant read actors. How can i fix this?

GetMoviesQuery

```
namespace WebApi.Application.MovieOperations.Queries.GetMovies
{
    public class GetMoviesQuery
    {
        private readonly IMovieStoreDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public GetMoviesQuery(IMovieStoreDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public List<GetMoviesModel> Handle()
        {
            var _movieList = _context.Movies.Include(x => x.Genre).Include(y => y.Director).OrderBy(z => z.Id).ToList<Movie>();
            List<GetMoviesModel> mv = _mapper.Map<List<GetMoviesModel>>(_movieList);
            return mv;
        }
    }
    public class GetMoviesModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Director { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include actors too

```
var _movieList = _context.Movies
                   .Include(x => x.Actors)
                    .Include(x => x.Genre)
                     .Include(y => y.Director)
                      .OrderBy(z => z.Id)
                      .ToList();
```

UPDATE:

If you only need the First and the last names of actors you will have to create a model class

```
public class ActorViewModel
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string SurName { get; set; }
}
```

and fix GetMoviesModel accordingly

```
 public class GetMoviesModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
       .....
        public ICollection<ActorViewModel> Actors { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i show only Actor name and Actor surname? When i did that, it showed every property of Actors. Is there any filtering option?

Comment: @Oguzhan You are welcome. Pls check my answer update